# Move or redirect or add a a link for closed questions to go to a different section of the site

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Archive Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60729/archive-questions)

Move or redirect or add a a link for closed questions to go to a different section of the site. Some of these question deserve to have a life and be helpful. If a question is helpful for 532 people in a world on 8 billion, I say it's still a good question. SO doesn't need to be selfish and only care for the masses.

Move these types of questions to another less used site instead of killing them just because they don't tank at the top of Google search.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. Are you suggesting that all closed questions must be migrated to another SE site?

Comment: Tony, you should search meta a little before posting. This has been discussed many times before.

Comment: How many of these questions are you going to ask in rapid succession?

Answer (score 3):

To keep a site manageable, on topic, of high value and clean, you need to set certain boundaries. And questions which do not fall within these boundaries often end up being closed. Unlike many other sites, a question being closed on SO is not necessarily a permanent state. If it can be improved to fit within the boundaries of the site, it can be reopened.

If that is not the case, it is simply not a good fit. I don't think it is up to SO/SE to provide the alternative where the question would be a decent fit, nor to provide a last resting place for them. Let SO/SE do what it does well and forget about the other stuff.

By all means, if there are any sites willing to step into a perceived gap that SO leaves, they should certainly do so. And good luck to them. I hope they will be successful. And if you think a site like that would be useful, by all means create one. But let SO be what it is.

Comment: I think I asked a question once if there are other similar sites and the question got closed. The reason wasn't convincing.

Comment: Without the exact question, I can't comment on why that was closed. And I honestly would not know what to recommend either. There are general forums out there which might accept such content. But I have a hard time thinking of an alternative of similar quality as SO is. There is sometimes content which I personally find interesting and hate to see deleted, but in the end SO can only be as good as it is, by enforcing some of the boundaries as I describe above.